# Accessing selected code using ReSharper SDK

Tags: resharper, resharper-7.1, resharper-plugins, resharper-sdk

Is there any way to recognize and extract a chunk of code that has been highlighted by clicking and dragging using the ReSharper SDK?

Comment: What do you mean by *clicking and dragging*? Do you mean to get the text selection from the editor? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, exactly: text selection from the editor.

Comment: But not selection using the caret...

Comment: Anyone? I want to be able to analyze the text selection from the editor and make sure it is a part of a method body.